# How to Send keyboard data to the Server using getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

I am using getJSON to send a request to server and fetch response. When I send an string of text like 'firstname=x' to the server, it works fine, but when I use '$('#input').val()' as input data to the server, it returns nothing as response.

Here is the jquery code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>Request in getJSON</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script src="jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
              $('#button').click(function(){
                 var req=$('#query').val();
                 var data='firstname=req';
                 $.getJSON('http://..../server.php?callback=?', data,function(res){                              
                    alert('Your name is '+res.fullname);
                 });//getJSON    
              }); //onclick
     });//on document ready
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Enter Name </h1>
<input type='text' id='query' />
<input type="button" id="button" value="submit" />
<div id="results"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope you can help me
Thank you

Comment: How are you using `$('#input').val()`? You should have posted the sample code that includes that instead of this code which works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this one:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#button').click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         var data={firstname : $('#query').val()}; //<--------try like this
         $.getJSON('http://..../server.php?callback=?', data,function(res){
             alert('Your name is '+res.fullname);
         });//getJSON    
     }); //onclick
 });//on document ready
```

Comment: Thanks Jai, Me and you could both correct it at the same time. I came back to remove this and saw your reply. Many thanks. I keep the post and wish it helps novices like me. My mistkae is here                  var data='firstname=req'; in this line there should not be any quote and equation mark should become colon, as Jai mentioned. Thanks Ja i again.

Comment: Okay great you debuged the code and found the error and I am glad if this helped you. Thanks.